# Legend produced by scale_fill_gradient() in ggplot2 returns a legend that is blank. How can I populate this?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

Specifically, I am trying to create a state heatmap in `ggplot2` using `geom_map` (please see code below).

I can produce the following easily:

[image]

As you can see, the legend on the right does not produce any color gradient.  I don't know what the issue is, and I am hoping someone can help me out!

I've created a dummy example below that has the same issue.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(maps)
states_map <- map_data("state")

states <-data.table(
  stateAbb=as.factor(c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA",
                       "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME",
                       "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS",  "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM",
                       "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN",
                       "TX", "UT", "VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY")),
  stateName=as.factor(c("alaska","alabama","arkansas","arizona","california","colorado",
                        "connecticut","district of columbia","delaware","florida","georgia",
                        "hawaii","iowa","idaho","illinois","indiana","kansas","kentucky",
                        "louisiana","massachusetts","maryland","maine","michigan","minnesota",
                        "missouri","mississippi","montana","north carolina","north dakota",
                        "nebraska","new hampshire","new jersey","new mexico","nevada",
                        "new york","ohio","oklahoma","oregon","pennsylvania","puerto rico",
                        "rhode island","south carolina","south dakota","tennessee","texas",
                        "utah","virginia","vermont","washington","wisconsin",
                        "west virginia","wyoming"))
)

states$value <- sample(1:10, nrow(states), TRUE)

plot1 <- ggplot(states, aes(map_id = stateName, fill = value)) + 
  geom_map(map = states_map, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "freq^.5", low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) +
  coord_map("polyconic")
```

Edits: Fixed missing library import

Comment: If you use `library(maps)` it works fine, also looks like you meant to have `states_map <- map_data("state")`

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  In my actual implementation, I have both library(maps) and states_map <- map_data("state").

Unfortunately, it still does not output on my machine.

Comment: maybe check for package updates, I am using `maps_3.1.1, ggplot2_2.2.0, data.table_1.9.6`. Also `R version 3.3.1`

Comment: Looks like I have an older version of maps (3.0.3) and ggplot2 (2.0.0).  Hopefully that does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know, happy to help work through a fix if that doesn't do it

Comment: Sorry i'm delayed in getting back to you.

I updated all outdated packages and confirmed I am on R 3.3.1.  Unfortunately, I am getting the same result.  I've tried running locally (Windows) as well on an AWS EC2 instance (linux) but still no luck!

Comment: No warning messages or other oddities of note?

Comment: I can't reproduce on R 3.3.1 with ggplot 2.2.0. Also my colors have actual yellow, while your screenshot doesn't (but your code does).

Comment: @NathanDay:  Unfortunately, there are no warnings/errors. 

I can get labels on things when I use something categorical such as the following:


'states_map1 <- data.table(states_map)'
'plot2 <- ggplot(data = states_map1, aes(x = lat, y = long, color = region)) +
  geom_point()'

When I want a continuous gradient, though, it fails.

Comment: @Axeman: I've updated the graph with the appropriate output.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with your read ins and `options(stringsAsFactors = T)`. I always set it to `FASLE` globally and maybe that is causing your woes. could you check `str()` on both of your data inputs

Comment: sapply(states_map, class)
       long         lat       group       order      region   subregion 
  "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "integer" "character" "character" 

                            
sapply(states, class)
 stateAbb stateName     value 
 "factor"  "factor" "integer"


PS: how do you do code inside a comment? :)